# Warning: variable does not need to be mutable, but i needs to be

Tags: rust

The compiler is returning unused mutable warning. Warning is returned on `deposit_amount` and `sender` variables.

```
fn try_deposit(
    deps: DepsMut,
    env: Env,
    info: MessageInfo,
    mut config: &mut ConfigInfo,
    priority: u8,
    from: Option<String>,
    amount: Option<Uint128>,
) -> StdResult<()> {
    //CHECKING: if the contract is in the correct status to perform this handle function.
    check_status(config.status, priority)?;

    let mut deposit_amount: Uint128 = Uint128::zero(); // A thin wrapper around u128 that is using strings for JSON encoding/decoding. More here:https://github.com/scrtlabs/cosmwasm/blob/secret/packages/std/src/math/uint128.rs
    let mut sender: Addr; // A human-readable address. More here https://github.com/scrtlabs/cosmwasm/blob/secret/packages/std/src/addresses.rs


            
    if from.as_ref().is_some() && amount.as_ref().is_some() {
                deposit_amount = check_if_valid_amount(&info, &config, true, amount)?;
                sender = deps.api.addr_validate(from.as_ref().unwrap().as_str())?;
            } else {
                //CHECKING: Amount of deposit > minimum deposit amount
                deposit_amount = check_if_valid_amount(&info, &config, false, None)?;
                sender = info.sender;
                }

//Using deposit_amount and sender here

Ok(())
}
```

`check_if_validate_amount` function

```
fn check_if_valid_amount(

) -> StdResult<Uint128> {
    let mut deposit_amount = Uint128::zero();

   //Extracting deposit amount 
    deposit_amount = extracted_amount
    return Ok(deposit_amount);
}
```

Comment: `sender` does not need to be mutable, `deposit_amount` does. Are you sure you are not getting "value written to is never read"?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yeap on the deposit_amount(edited)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, any ideas? Seems like this happens cause of if-else?

Comment: What is your actual question here? Do you not understand how to fix the warning? Or are you asking why it is reported?

Comment: @user4815162342 both

Comment: If you declare something with `let foo: u32` and then assign to it just once, that doesn't count as mutation, but as initialization. That's why the compiler tells you that the variable doesn't need to be `mut`. And you typically fix it just by removing the unneeded `mut`.

Comment: @user4815162342 And what about the sender variable? If I left deposit_amount uninitialized it give same used mut warning

Comment: @HaseebSaeed The exact same applies to `sender`.

Comment: @user4815162342 makes sense. That's the correct answer btw. Can you answer this question so I can approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a variable with `let variable;` or `let variable: Type;`, and then assign to it just once, that doesn't count as mutation, but as delayed initialization. That's why the compiler tells you that the variable doesn't need to be `mut`.

To fix it, you just need to remove the unneeded `mut`. In your case this applies to both `sender` and `deposit_amount` (once you remove the unneeded initialization from the latter).